# First index pivot rule in LPSolve

Tags: linear-programming

I am working on a paper on how pivot rule selection influences the time needed for LPSolve to solve a problem. I have decided to write some teory about different algorithms, but i can't find anything about the "First index" algorithm.

Anybody know what it is, maybe know anything I could use as literature about it?